# Javascript - if statement not changing image src

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm just wondering if anyone can point out to me where I'm going wrong..
Here I have a small snippet of code that I would like to use to toggle between two images based on an onclick event. However, upon clicking on the image nothing happens. I placed an alert within the click function, which successfully triggered; though, when an alert was placed within the if statement, no alert was triggered. What did I mess up?

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="../CSS/209.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

 <div id="trim">green209green209green209</div>

 <h1 align="right">about House Felice</h1>

<center>

 <img src="../Images/fakevid.png" width="70%" height="48%"><img src="../Images/videonav1.png" width="25%" height="48%">


<div id="wrapper">

<div id="kitchen" align="left"> 
    <img id="pricetile1" src="../Images/kitchen.png">
    <img id="pricetile2" src="../Images/french.png" data-price="100" />
    <img id="pricetile3" src="../Images/german.png" data-price="200" />
</div>

<div id="floor" align="left">
    <img id="pricetile1" src="../Images/floors.png">
    <img id="pricetile4" src="../Images/mixed.png" data-price="300">
    <img id="pricetile5" src="../Images/allwood.png" data-price="400">
</div>

<div id="energy" align="left">
    <img id="pricetile1" src="../Images/energy.png">
    <img id="pricetile6" src="../Images/green.png" data-price="500">
    <img id="pricetile7" src="../Images/standard.png" data-price="600">
</div>
</div>



<div id="price"><p>total: $<span id="total">0.00</span><p></div>
<div id="next"> <p>next house</p></div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>


 <script>


             $('#pricetile2').click(function(){

    console.log(document.getElementById("pricetile2").src);
    if (document.getElementById("pricetile2").getAttribute('src') == "../Images/french.png" )
    {
        document.getElementById("pricetile2").getAttribute('src') = "../Images/french2.png";
        console.log(1);
    }
    else 
    {
        document.getElementById("pricetile2").getAttribute('src') = "../Images/french.png";
        console.log(2);
    }   
 });

 var container = document.getElementById('wrapper');
 var lines = container.children;
 var numLines = lines.length;
 document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.tagName == 'IMG' && container.contains(e.target)) {
var selected = e.target.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('selected');
if (selected.length)
  selected[0].className = selected[0].className.replace('selected', '');
e.target.className = 'selected';
var total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < numLines; i++) {
  var selected = lines[i].getElementsByClassName('selected');
  if (selected.length)
    total = total + Number(selected[0].dataset.price);
}
document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = Number(total).toFixed(2);
}
}, false);


 document.getElementById("calc").innerHTML = x;

</script>
```

Comment: Since you are already using jQuery you might try:  $('#pricetile2').attr("src", "../Images/french2.png");

Comment: What do you see if you `alert(document.getElementById("pricetile2").src)`?

Comment: your code is working. here's the fiddle with your code http://jsfiddle.net/21opzcq0/

Comment: @Sushil I deleted that, because he says he gets an alert outside the `if`, but not inside it. So the problem is with the `if` condition.

Comment: Also, I would not use src in your IF logic as it might not be what you expect. And I think that's the problem here ... it's always false and the image never changes.

Comment: oh. but the if condition works fine. its the path i guess, thats wrong

Comment: You have a couple of errors. Use .setAttribute('src', "../Images/french.png"); in your if block.

Comment: Great!  And please consider accepting the answer from Drakes or klickagent.ch. They both provided nice solutions to the original problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
console.log(document.getElementById("pricetile2").src);
```

shows the full url to the image instead of the relative path. eg. its not ../Images/french.png, but http://fiddle.jshell.net/Images/french.png (see http://jsfiddle.net/klickagent/wr01jxmb/)

therefore you need to check the full url to the image in the if statement.

As Barmar wrote: use

```
document.getElementById('pricetile2').getAttribute('src');
```

this gives you the relative path (the exact value in the src tag)

Comment: Or use `.getAttribute('src')` instead of `.src`.

Comment: That's interesting.  I always assumed that obj.getAttribute('src') would return the same value as obj.src ... but it doesn't.

Comment: So i just tried all of these suggestions, however, still no success :( I will edit post with the current, full code. Maybe the issue is elsewhere?

Answer (score 2):

The fastest change for this code to work is to change

```
if (document.getElementById("pricetile2").src == "../Images/french.png")
```

to

```
if (document.getElementById("pricetile2").src.indexOf("Images/french.png") >= 0)
```

or

```
if (document.getElementById("pricetile2").getAttribute("src") == "../Images/french.png")
```

because relative URLs cannot be directly compared as in your first attempt. (Credit for no.2 is Barmar)

Answer (score 1):

since you're using jQuery, I recommend using jQuery for your src definition as well. With that said, using jQuery's `.attr()` function, you can do:

```
$('#pricetile2').click(function(){

    if ( $("#pricetile2").attr('src') == "../Images/french.png" ) 
    {
        $("#pricetile2").attr('src','../Images/french2.png');
    }
    else 
    {
        $("#pricetile2").attr('src','../Images/french.png');
    }   
});
```

The reason your if statement doesn't work, is because `document.getElementById("pricetile2").src` will return the absolute path, not relative path (eg. that will return `http://example.com/Images/french.png`).